# Sort a vector of user made objects (with classes)

Tags: c++, stdvector

So far all the other questions and answers I have seen are using `struct` as the object. My code is

```
class Thing
{
private:
  string name;
  double balance;
public:
  string getName(){return name;}
  double getBalance(){return balance;}
};

bool sortByName(const Thing &lower, const Thing &upper)
{return (lower.getName() < upper.getName());}

bool sortByBalance(const Thing &lower, const Thing &upper)
{return (lower.getBalance() < upper.getBalance());}

int main()
{
  vector<Thing> myvec
  //Code to add objects with attributes

  sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), sortByName);
  sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), sortByBalance);
  //Code to display rearranged vector
```

The `getName()` and `getBalance()` is to return the name of the object, which are private variables in the class.

How do I compare the two values from the different classes, and then implement them in the sort function?

*Edit: I added the definition of the Thing class at the beginning

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: The error message I have been getting is ```main.cpp:16:24: error: passing ‘const Person’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 {return (lower.getName() < upper.getName());}
```
and I don't know if it's due to the comparison itself or the calling of the functions

Comment: Note that you have a vector of `Thing`, not a vector of `Person`. What exactly do `getName()` and `getBalance()` return? If they return `std::string` or a built-in numeric type then those are already comparable and you don't need to change anything.

Comment: ```getName()``` returns a string and ``getBalance()``` returns a double

Comment: Please show a [mre], including the definition of your class. I'm going to guess that `getName` and `getBalance` aren't `const` functions, so you can't call them on `const` objects.

Comment: What exactly is a `Thing`? Your compare functions expect a `Person`.

Comment: So the error I was getting in compilation was due to the presence of the ```const``` objects, but though it compiles, it doesn't display the order of the vector any differently

Comment: You need to show actual code. We can't tell from what is in the question. My guess for your last comment is that you're sorting a copy of the vector.

Comment: The last comment for displaying the vector is a for loop that calls each function for each object in the vector

Comment: "_all the other questions and answers I have seen are using `struct` as the object_" - A `struct` is a `class`, with only slightly different accessibility defaults, so whatever worked in the other answers should work for you too.

Comment: "_How do I compare the two values from the different classes_" - You could make  `operator<` overloads, like `bool operator<(const ClassA&, const ClassB&);` - but I see only one class in your code, `Thing`. It seems like `Person` is the interesting class here.

Comment: I added ```bool operator<(Thing &lower, Thing &upper) {return lower.getName() < upper.getName();}, and that works for comparing the names, but the problem is distinguishing between the string variable and the double variable

Comment: Have you made an error in the example? You talk about comparing different classes and you have shown the definition of the `Thing` class but not for the `Person` class. Are they the same class? Also clarify what the problem is distinguishing between the string variable and the double variable. I don't understand that.

Comment: Whoops, yes. Person has some extra functionality that I have already tested, but Thing is what I was using in a dummy program, essentially scratch work

Comment: Oh, ok, so [this](https://godbolt.org/z/khG_pE) is what you want?

Comment: It still says that you want to "_compare the two values from the different classes_" - but there's only _one_ class and you want to compare different instances of that one class, right?

Comment: The code in the link solved my problem. I was able to sort all the values I wanted to

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `getName` and `getBalance` as const functions.

```
class Person
{
  ...
  const string& getName() const { return name; }
}
```

Comment: The methods don't need to *return* `const` values (but that is certainly a good thing to do), however the methods *themselves* do need to be marked as `const` since they are being called on `const` objects.